# Validating CSS text transformations on text in a test

Tags: css, dom, ui-testing, react-testing-library

I have a made a React component that will truncate long text using an ellipsis. For the case of adding the prop `line-count=2` it will utilize [`line-clamp` to do this over multiple lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp#Example).

Now, how would I test that this actually happens in the output generated by the browser (as seen by the user)? CSS transforms doesn't change anything in the DOM, so if I would get the element block and test for `innerText`, that will not show any text transformations that has happened in the browser.

Can this be done using client side DOM scripting a la `react-testing-library` or would I need a heavier option like Selenium or OCR (*way* too heavy)?